# check if widget is combobox

Tags: python, pyqt

as the title says, how do I check if a dynamically created widget is a combobox?

I've tried the simple if statement:

```
for keys,values in self.setCDict.iteritems():
        if values == QtGui.QComboBox():
             pass
        # do this and that
```

But it doesn't work. I put a breakpoint in the If statement, I see the QtGui.QComboBox which is equal to QtGui.QComboBox() on the otherside. Even tried without the brackets, but nothing.

Comment: Do you mean to check if `values` [is an instance of](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) `QComboBox`?

Comment: what about `isinstance(values,QtGui.QComboBox)`

Comment: working. Thank you.